# jquery Waterfall plugin's wait until images load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, waterfall

I am using the waterfall plugin for jQuery on my site.  I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and I am using Knockout.js for my js viewmodel.  The data is from a ajax call to a web api service that return JSON objects to the knockout viewmodel.  The images are all blobs inside an azure storage container.

[Waterfall plugin home](http://dmitry-ivanov.me/projects/waterfall/#options-case)

I initialize the plugin in the following way as the OP indicates in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437679/only-apply-jquery-waterfall-reflow-after-the-images-have-loaded):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // apply jQuery Waterfall plugin
    $("#ProductList").waterfall({
        colMinWidth: 230,
        defaultContainerWidth: 970,
        autoresize: true
    });

    $('#ProductList').load(function () {
        $("#ProductList").waterfall('reflow');
    })
});
```

I use the window.load function because as I understand, it waits for all Dom elements to load.

### PROBLEM:

But when a site loads for the first time, with no cache, the waterfall plugin does not render properly (as in the object sizes are not applied to the page so they overlap and the page height is too short for all the page objects).  But if I refresh the page the waterfall plugin renders properly every page request after the first page load.

I also tried placing this waterfall initialization in the following page function:

```
$(document).ready(function ()

});
```

But the same problem exists.

Google chrome dev tools is not showing any js errors on the page.

### QUESTION

Can someone help me get this waterfall plugin to fire after all imgaes have loaded.

Thanks in advance.

## Further Detail:

Here is my knockout.js HTML template:

```
<div id="ProductList" class=""
    data-bind="template: {
    foreach: filterProducts,
    beforeRemove: hideProductElement,
    afterAdd: showProductElement,
    afterRender: reFlow
}">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" data-bind="text: ProductId">
        <div class="kr_pr_box">
            <%-- BANNER PANEL--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --%>
            <div data-bind="if: StatusName">
                <div class="kr_pr_box_banner_box">
                    <span id="dnn_BannerLable" class="kr_pr_box_banner" data-bind="text: StatusName"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <%-- IMAGE PANEL-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --%>
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: DetailUrl }" title="View Full Detail">
                <img data-bind="attr: { src: Url300 }">
            </a>
            <%-- TITLE PANEL-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --%>
            <div class="kr_pr_box_detail">
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: DetailUrl }" title="View Full Detail">
                    <label data-bind="text: Name"></label>
                </a>
                <label data-bind="text: ShortInfo" class="kr_pr_box_caption"></label>
            </div>
            <%-- PRICE PANEL-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --%>
            <label data-bind="text: formatCurrency(Price)" class="kr_pr_box_price"></label>
            <%-- CART PANEL-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --%>
            <div class="kr_pr_box_addcart">
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="CartLink" ToolTip="Add to Cart" NavigateUrl="~/ModuleDevelopment/KrisisStore.aspx">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </div>
            <%-- EDIT / DELETE PANEL -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --%>
            <asp:Panel ID="AdminPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <div class="kr_pr_box_admin">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" ResourceKey="EditProduct.Text" Visible="false" Enabled="false" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" ResourceKey="DeleteProduct.Text" CommandName="DeleteProduct" ToolTip="Add to Cart" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID")%>' />
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what the HTML gets rendered as (I only included the first element in the ko repeat for brevity):

```
<div id="ProductList" class="" data-bind="template: {
    foreach: filterProducts,
    beforeRemove: hideProductElement,
    afterAdd: showProductElement,
    afterRender: reFlow
}" style="position: relative; min-height: 1112px;">

<div style="position: absolute; width: calc(25% - 0px); transform: translate3d(calc(0% + 0px), 0px, 0px);">
        <input type="hidden" data-bind="text: ProductId"></input>
        <div class="kr_pr_box">

            <div data-bind="if: StatusName"></div>


            <a data-bind="attr: { href: DetailUrl }" title="View Full Detail" href="http://www.dnndev.me/Module-Development/Krisis-Store/ctl/Detail/mid/2601/id/17/item/Test-Product-62">
                <img data-bind="attr: { src: Url300 }" src="https://giselledenis.blob.core.windows.net/products/product-name-Medium300.jpg">
            </a>

            <div class="kr_pr_box_detail">
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: DetailUrl }" title="View Full Detail" href="http://www.dnndev.me/Module-Development/Krisis-Store/ctl/Detail/mid/2601/id/17/item/Test-Product-62">
                    <label data-bind="text: Name">Test Product 62</label>
                </a>
                <label data-bind="text: ShortInfo" class="kr_pr_box_caption">A test product for krisis store</label>
            </div>

            <label data-bind="text: formatCurrency(Price)" class="kr_pr_box_price">$175.00</label>

            <div class="kr_pr_box_addcart">
                <a id="dnn_ctr2601_View_ctl00_CartLink" title="Add to Cart" href="/ModuleDevelopment/KrisisStore.aspx">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                </a>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a little complex, here we have an very simple option: [bootstrap-waterfall](https://github.com/Mystist/bootstrap-waterfall), strongly recommended.